# What could be the datatype of "value" in this JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to parse json object using Java.

This is a JSONObject : I am unable to identify, what type is "value". 
"value" stores two ways 
1st:

```
{
            "name": <String>,
            "place": <String>,
            "scope": <String>,
            "value":"Place" <String(possible choice)>
}
```

2nd:

```
{
    "name": <String>,
    "place": <String>,
    "scope": <String>,
    "value": {
        "placeToSee1": {
            "location": 1,
            "time": ""
        },
        "placeToSee2": {
            "location": 1,
            "time": " 16:30",
            "accDays": ""
        },
        "placeToSee3": {
            "location": 1,
            "time": " 16:30",
            "accDays": ""
        },....
    }
}
```

Any help on figuring out what could be the datatype of "value" and how to parse into "value" and retrieve data of "placeToSee1", "location", "time".

Comment: [check this page](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: 1) `<String>` is not valid JSON. --- 2) `value`, `placeToSee1`, `placeToSee2`, ... are all JSON Objects, same as your outer structure.

Comment: If i consider it as JSONObject then it throw me an error, 
`code`org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["value"] is not a JSONObject.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:647)
 at getData.test.main(test.java:74)`

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).